# MVVMCross ShowViewModel marshalling

Tags: mvvmcross

I have taken ownership of an existing MVVMCross application which currently directly calls ShowViewModel from a non-ui thread.

Does this automatically marshall to the UI thread?

Comment: I disagree. It was a clear question and William Barbosa answered it succinctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MvxNavigatingObject` [calls](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/f7fcf18d960f578b851837f2aaaeb4d0e3b72364/MvvmCross/Core/Core/ViewModels/MvxNavigatingObject.cs#L106-L115) the [`IMvxViewDispatcher`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/f7fcf18d960f578b851837f2aaaeb4d0e3b72364/MvvmCross/Core/Core/Views/IMvxViewDispatcher.cs). Every default implementation of the `IMvxViewDispatcher` makes use of `RequestMainThreadAction` before calling the `Show` method of the presenter. So unless your codebase is using custom dispatcher (or a custom presenter that runs code on some other thread), all ViewModels are being shown in the UI thread already.

Comment: Thank you William. Clearly explained.